# Families of quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^4$ passing through six points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quadratic-forms

For given $n,m \geq 1$, consider the set of $n$-tuples of quadratic forms $(Q_1, \cdots, Q_n)$ with $Q_j \in \mathbb{C}[x_0, \cdots, x_5]$ for $j = 1, \cdots, n$, which vanish at a fixed set of points $\{\mathbf{y}^{(1)}, \cdots, \mathbf{y}^{(m)}\} \subset \mathbb{P}^4(\mathbb{C})$. That is, for each $1 \leq i \leq n$ and $1 \leq j \leq m$,  we have $Q_i(\mathbf{y}^{(j)}) = 0$.

For $(n,m) = (9,6)$ and $(14, 6)$, how do we characterize the set of $n$-tuples $(Q_1, \cdots, Q_n)$ vanishing at a prescribed set of $m$ points?

Comment: I think you have one variable too many in your polynomial ring.

Comment: To address your question: the space of quadratic forms in $d+1$ variables is a vector space $V$ of dimension ${d+3 \choose 2}$. For any fixed set of $m$ points in $\mathbf P^d$, the space of quadratic forms vanishing at those points is a subspace $W \subset V$. For a general choice of points $W$ will have codimension $m$ in $V$, but for some choices the codimension will be less. The set you are asking about is then $W^n$ (if you look at ordered $n$-tuples) or $\operatorname{Sym}^n(W)$ (if you look at unorderded tuples). Is this the kind of description you want?